# Align multiple images to center with margin between them

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to align these three images to center and make it responsive so they stack one under the other, but I can't figure out why the container about__inner always goes slightly to the left..? Here's the Codepen link: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PbpMbj

```css
section.about {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
.small__title {
  font-family: 'Kaushan Script', cursive;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.big__title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.description {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.about__images {
  max-width: 780px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.about__inner {
  margin-top: 60px;
  float: left;
}
.about__inner img {
  max-width: 240px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section class="about">
  <h5 class="small__title">lorem</h5>
  <h4 class="big__title">Lorem lorem</h4>
  <hr class="horizontal__rule">
  <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae commodi nisi aut animi, excepturi impedit dicta natus culpa. Veniam atque sapiente assumenda fugiat tempore ipsam eos quae</p>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row about__images">
      <div class="about__inner first">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=36&txt=383%C3%97262&w=383&h=262" alt="">
        <div class="about__inner--overlay">
          <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <p>LOREM IPSUM</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="about__inner">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=36&txt=383%C3%97262&w=383&h=262" alt="">
        <div class="about__inner--overlay">
          <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <p>LOREM IPSUM</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="about__inner">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=36&txt=383%C3%97262&w=383&h=262" alt="">
        <div class="about__inner--overlay">
          <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <p>LOREM IPSUM</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are already using *Bootstrap* then just use its default classes for better alignment as:

### Code Snippet:

```css
section.about {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
.small__title {
  font-family: 'Kaushan Script', cursive;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.big__title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.description {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 12px;
}
/*.about__images,
.about__images * {
   box-sizing: content-box;
}*/

.about__images {
  max-width: 780px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.about__inner {
  margin-top: 60px;
}
.about__inner img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<section class="about">
  <h5 class="small__title">lorem</h5>
  <h4 class="big__title">Lorem lorem</h4>
  <hr class="horizontal__rule">
  <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae commodi nisi aut animi, excepturi impedit dicta natus culpa. Veniam atque sapiente assumenda fugiat tempore ipsam eos quae</p>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="about__images">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="about__inner col-md-4">
          <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=36&txt=383%C3%97262&w=383&h=262" alt="">
          <div class="about__inner--overlay">
            <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <p>LOREM IPSUM</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="about__inner col-md-4">
          <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=36&txt=383%C3%97262&w=383&h=262" alt="">
          <div class="about__inner--overlay">
            <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <p>LOREM IPSUM</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="about__inner col-md-4">
          <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=36&txt=383%C3%97262&w=383&h=262" alt="">
          <div class="about__inner--overlay">
            <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <p>LOREM IPSUM</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Also the [**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/vivekkupadhyay/pen/mOWNXw)

Answer (score 0):

Try it with flex.
Add

```
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;

-webkit-flex-direction: column-reverse;
flex-direction: column-reverse;
```

to your `.about__images` class

```css
section.about {
      font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .small__title {
      font-family: 'Kaushan Script', cursive;
      font-size: 16px;
    }
    
    .big__title {
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    
    .description {
      width: 700px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      font-size: 12px;
    }
    
    .about__images {
      max-width: 780px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -moz-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: flex;
  
     -webkit-flex-direction: column-reverse;
     flex-direction: column-reverse;
    }
    
    .about__inner {
      margin-top: 60px;
      float: left;
    }
    
    .about__inner img {
      max-width: 240px;
      margin-right: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<section class="about">
      <h5 class="small__title">lorem</h5>
      <h4 class="big__title">Lorem lorem</h4>
      <hr class="horizontal__rule">
      <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae commodi nisi aut animi, excepturi impedit dicta natus culpa. Veniam atque sapiente assumenda fugiat tempore ipsam eos quae</p>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row about__images">
          <div class="about__inner first">
            <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=36&txt=383%C3%97262&w=383&h=262" alt="">
            <div class="about__inner--overlay">
              <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <p>LOREM IPSUM</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="about__inner">
            <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=36&txt=383%C3%97262&w=383&h=262" alt="">
            <div class="about__inner--overlay">
              <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <p>LOREM IPSUM</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="about__inner">
            <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=36&txt=383%C3%97262&w=383&h=262" alt="">
            <div class="about__inner--overlay">
              <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <p>LOREM IPSUM</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox to center the images with space around them, and add a media query to make them stack under a certain width.

```
.about__images {
  max-width: 780px;
  margin: 60px auto 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

@media (max-width:1000px) {
  .about__images {
    display: block;
  }
  .about__inner {
    text-align: center;
  }
}

.about__inner {

}

.about__inner img {
  max-width: 240px;
}
```

Here's your code using flexbox on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NbpQyz).